# Compiler's alleged optimisation of while loop

Tags: c, performance, assembly, while-loop

In [this](https://youtu.be/cZj284kfuE8?t=6m11s) segment of an embedded programming lecture, Dr. Samek explains how the compiler is able to realise efficiencies over the "original code" (presumably by this he means an implementation dictated by the logical order of the syntax):

> I hope you have noticed
>   that the disassembled code implements a different flow of control from
>   what I've described for the while loop. The original code was supposed
>   to test the condition first and then jump over the loop body if the
>   condition wasn't true. The compiled code starts with an unconditional
>   branch and reverses the order of the loop body and the testing of the
>   condition. When you think about it, though, those two flows of control
>   are equivalent, except the generated one is faster, because it has only
>   one conditional branch at the bottom of the loop.

Throughout his explanation, he draws reference to the two flow charts shown. The chart depicting the compiled code illustrates how "it has only one conditional branch at the bottom of the loop." I can't seem to see how this works in practice:

- [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pu0ji9h5aja7jql/while.mov?dl=0) is a screen-capture I took showing how the original code would be implemented. Sequence of (initial) machine instructions:

`0x2815    CMP` -> `0x1c40     ADDS` ->`repeat until condition is false`

- [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7lpdq3116xowc1r/disassembled.mov?dl=0) is another screen-capture showing the sequence used by the compiler. Sequence of (initial) machine instructions:

`0x2815    CMP` -> `0xdbfc     BLT.N` -> `0x1c40     ADDS` -> `repeat until condition is false`

I can understand how both flows of control are equivalent (at least from the diagrams alone), but certainly *not* how the generated one (on the right) is faster. First, the arrows at the very beginning of both diagrams lead to the very same branches. Second, although the branch does seem to occur later on in the schematic on the right, as you've seen from the screen-captures, the simulator seems to show that *both* methods commence with the machine instructions pertaining to the comparison (`0x2815    CMP`).

How can I reconcile the flow-charts to what I'm seeing in practice?

Comment: I have no idea whether your screen captures are any different. I could not find any difference by looking at them. I cannot pipe videos through `diff`. Please use text whenever possible.

Comment: I flipped between the screen-caps.  The code is the same, it's just paused at a different point.  And annoyingly, the whole window is offset a bit, so everything moves a small amount when flipping between them https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_comparator style.

Comment: @PeterCordes The code in both screen-caps are indeed exactly the same. Why would they be any different? My question is entirely to do with how the compiler is able to execute the while loop at the machine level more efficiently. The difference lies solely between the two sequences of machine instructions, which you may observe by directing your attention to the "Disassembly" pane in the middle, and comparing the machine instructions of the while loop - beginning from CMP. (i've already written the two sets of instructions in text - see above).

Comment: I meant the disassembly was the same.  Sorry that wasn't clear by the time I was done editting my comment.

Comment: @n.m. The screen-captures (and the differences therein) were described explicitly in text. I've provided the screen-captures so that the machine instructions i've provided could be taken as a given without having to watch the video I linked in its entirety. Keep in mind, in the original version of my question I highlighted the fact that I'm a beginner in programming at the machine-level.

Comment: The description makes no sense and does not seem to correspond to the captures. A loop implementation normally has at least one jump instruction somewhere. Your first text description lacks a jump. Your two screen captures seem to be depict two programs made up of the exact same assembly instructions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I concur with Kerren SB's answer. I'll discuss it in more detail:

The original logic has the following jump instructions that are executed during each iteration:

```
begin_loop:
    cmp counter, 21
    jge end_loop           ; jump when greater or equal
    ...
    jmp begin_loop
end_loop:
    ....
```

The revised logic executes one instruction less during each iteration:

```
    jmp test_loop          ; executed once; not part of loop
begin_loop:
    ...
test_loop:
    cmp counter, 21
    jlt begin_loop         ; jump when less than
    ...
```

So in the loop the unconditional `jmp begin_loop` is saved.

Comment: and hence is more likely to stay in the instruction cache

Comment: @EvilTeach,if you mean that the unconditional jump is more likely to stay in the cache: that depends on the length of the loop and everything that happens in it, such as procedure calls. The cache does not keep individual instructions, but blocks of instructions. If you mean that the loop block is more likely to stay in the cache because it is smaller, then, yes, you are right. But in all cases, in absolute terms an instruction in the loop is saved.

Comment: Ya.  I recall compilers in the 70s would init the loop variable then jump to the end of a do while to implement a while loop.

Answer (score 5):

The only instructions that *matter* are the ones that are repeated in every loop round. And the point of the rearrangement of the logic is that there is only one jump *per loop round*. There may be several jumps before and after the entire loop, but we don't care about those. The only things that are expensive are the ones that are done over and over.